# Alexa Request Interceptor - Cant kill the session

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

Is it possible to have a RequestInterceptor abort the Session based on some logic inside the RequestInterceptor?

I have a routine coded that verifies the validity of a User. If the validity check fails, I want to play a message to the USer and abort the session.

What I see happening is that the LaunchRequest still runs even though I try and kill the seesion in the RequestInterceptor

A simplified version is as follows

```
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk-core');

const requestInterceptor = {
  var isUserOk = false;

  if(!isUserOk){
    process(handlerInput) {
     return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak("You are inside the Request Interceptor")
      .withShouldEndSession(true)
      .getResponse();
    }
  }
}

const launchRequestHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return (handlerInput.requestEnvelope.session.new && 
            handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'LaunchRequest');
},
handle(handlerInput) {
  return handlerInput.responseBuilder
    .speak("Hi, welcome to the test skill. What is your name?")
    .reprompt("You did not respond. Please tell me your name")
    .getResponse();
  }
};

const skillBuilder = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom();

exports.handler = skillBuilder
         .addRequestHandlers(
                  launchRequestHandler,
         )
        .addRequestInterceptors(
                 requestInterceptor
         )
        .lambda();
```

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to have the logic in the RequestInterceptor kill off the Session and prevent the LaunchRequest handler from running?

Thanks

-bc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because interceptors do not return responses (note that the interceptor method is called `process()` and not `handle()`) In the interceptor, instead of trying to close the session, use the `handlerInput` to set a session attribute named e.g. `validUser`:

```
let attributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
attributes.validUser = isUserOk(); //call your user check function here
handlerInput.attributesManager.setSessionAttributes(attributes);
```

Now create a launchRequestBadUserHandler where in the `canHandle()` you require that session attribute to be false:

```
const attributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
const isUserOk = attributes.validUser;
canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return (handlerInput.requestEnvelope.session.new && 
                handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'LaunchRequest' &&
                !isUserOk);
```

In this handler `handle()` function send the response you originally planned for the interceptor. Don't forget to call this handler **before** your original launch request handler in `addRequestHandlers()`